# How to display model fields from another model using nested resource rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

I have 3 models, first product model, invoice and invoice_detail.

Invoice(Parent) and invoice detail(Child) are nested resource.

Am adding products from invoice detail model, that's working fine, the problem is when am trying to display in a table the name of the product that was added, am getting the follow error:

Thanks in advance!!

**invoices/show.html.erb**

```
undefined method `name' for 2:Integer
```

**invoices/show.html.erb**

```
<% @invoice.invoice_details.each do |invoice_detail| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= invoice_detail.product_id.name %></td>
          <td><%= number_to_currency invoice_detail.product_id.price %></td>
          <td><%= invoice_detail.product_id.quantity %></td>
          <td><%= number_to_currency invoice_detail.total_amt %></td>

          <td>


              <%= link_to "Destroy", 
                                    [@invoice, invoice_detail],
                                    method: :delete,
                                    remote: true,
                                    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
                                    class: "btn btn-default"%> 
          </td>
         </tr>
        <% end %>
```

**models/product.erb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :warehouse
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoice_details
end
```

**models/invoice.erb**

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :warehouse
  belongs_to :invoice_type
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :invoice_details, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**models/invoice_detail.erb**

```
class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tax
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view,

`<%= invoice_detail.product_id.name %>`

should be

`<%= invoice_detail.product.name %>`

Comment: It doesn't work my friend. Now am getting **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass** @Andy